# Is there a way to write better regex when we have so much ORs

Tags: python, regex

I have this following regex, starts with `09` and has a 2 digit number that should be only in some specific numbers, then 7 digits:

```
^[0][9](11|12|13|14|15|16|17|90|91|92|93|94|30|33|35|36|37|38|39|01|02|03|04|05|41|20|21|22|32|31|34|42)[0-9]{7}$
```

Or in python:

```py
numbers = r"11|12|13|14|15|16|17|90|91|92|93|94|30|33|35|36|37|38|39|01|02|03|04|05|41|20|21|22|32|31|34|42"
phone_number_regex = rf"^[0][9]({numbers})[0-9]{7}$"
```

Is there a way to make this regex shorter? there is too much `|`s.

Comment: "there is too much `|` s" - and? Is it a problem? As an alternative, you could use regex to verify that there are two digits and check these digits against the allowed list in python, not regex. So you'd still have the list in the code, but the regex would be shorter.

Comment: no this is not a problem, but its not so readable.

Comment: Your python version looks quite readable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the alternatives, it seems the following matches the same things:

```
^09(0[1-5]|1[1-7]|2[012]|3[0-9]|4[12]|9[0-4])[0-9]{7}$
```

Comment: If numbers in this list have business meaning (like allowed area codes in phone number), then compression like this completely hides it. Yes, the regex is shorter, but at what cost? :)

Comment: Depending on your personal experience, this form of writing alternatives is perfectly readable @SergioTulentsev. Either way, the question was if it could be written "shorter".

Comment: @JvdV: yeah, I'm just thinking out loud. Your version is not identical to the original expression, btw. It rejects 20, for example. Maybe others too. My point was: the list may be long, but it's nearly impossible to mess it up. Unlike this scheme. Especially when one needs to add/remove numbers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, good point indeed. I missed the 20. Will edit now.

Comment: Anyway, good stuff. +1

Comment: This is what I have used: `^09(0[1-5]|1[1-8]|2[0-2]|3[0-9]|4[12]|9[0-4])[0-9]{7}$`. Thank you, it helped so much

Comment: You could also change the `[0-9]{7}` to `\d{7}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile so I can't do the string split and sort to get the full thing, but what you can do is use character ranges to handle each group.

```
11|12|13|14|15|16|17|...
```

becomes

```
1[1-7]|...
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was exactly what I was looking for.